# .ContainsKey() gives error for ordered hash table

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a Powershell script to make the task of changing file properties easier.  Here is a snippet that's got an issue -

```
$datePropertyToChange = "create"

$properties = [ordered]@{}
$properties.create = "CreationTime"
$properties.write = "LastWriteTime"
$properties.access = "LastAccessTime"

Write-Host ($properties.ContainsKey($datePropertyToChange))
```

This produces the following error -

> Method invocation failed because
> [System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary] does not contain a
> method named 'ContainsKey'.

However, when the hash table definition is modified to be `$properties = @{}` then the error goes away.  Is there a way to keep the hash table ordered but still have the use of `.ContainsKey()`?

Comment: a hash table is not ordered...if you need a hybrid between a hash and an array...perhaps use a sorted dictionary? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-6.0

Comment: The error message should be self-explanatory, `Specialized.OrderedDictionary` doesn't have that method, you should use `.Contains('key')` instead.

Comment: Use `Contains()` instead (both hashtables and dictionaries [have it in common](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.contains))

Comment: @Ctznkane525, "ordered hashtable" is PowerShell's term (and syntax, via the `[ordered]` pseudo cast) for the [`System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary) type, which enumerates its entries in _definition order_, which is not the same as _sort order_ (as maintained by the distinct [`System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary\`2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.SortedDictionary-2) type you link to).

Answer (score 3):

In situations where you want to be able to use a dictionary in place of a hashtable (or vice-versa), you should always code against their shared interface: [System.Collections.IDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary).

If you look at the documentation, you'll find that it prescribes implementation of [a `Contains()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.contains), which:

> Determines whether the IDictionary object contains an element with the specified key.

... exactly what you want here:

```
function Test-HasAllKeys
{
  param([System.Collections.IDictionary]$Dictionary, [string[]]$Keys)

  foreach($key in $Keys){
    if(-not $Dictionary.Contains($key)){
      return $false
    }
  }

  return $true
}
```

The above function will work regardless of whether it's a regular hashtable or an ordered dictionary, as long as the type implements `IDictionary`:

```
PS ~> Test-HasAllKeys @{ A = 1; B = 2; C = 3; } -Keys A,B,C
True
PS ~> Test-HasAllKeys ([ordered]@{ A = 1; B = 2; C = 3; }) -Keys A,B,C
True
PS ~> Test-HasAllKeys @(-split 'A B C') -Keys A,B,C
Test-HasAllKeys : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Dictionary'. Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type
"System.Collections.IDictionary".
```